# Liquid metal ball in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making my first steps coding with JavaScript and playing with three.js too.

I have been studying watching this amazing tutorial of Paul Lewis to make an interactive liquid metal ball: http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/create-interactive-liquid-metal-ball-webgl-4126370

I was asking me if it's possible to make something like this but with an external JSON model and not a three.js basic geometry. I've been watching
on internet and the most similar example that I found is this monkey http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/undulating-monkey/ but it works with something called A3. Do you know some example made with Three.js?

Comment: Yes it is, up to you to define what part the mouse will interact with if it is not a sphere. In your second example it is just a sine/cosine vertex shader changing over time, not a liquid implementation like the first example. You seem to have everything needed in this first example to implement that on a JSON of yours.

Comment: So yo mean that is possible make something like the second example in three.js using vertex shader?

Comment: yep, import your json and define a vertex shader that moves vertices with a cosine / sine function of time.

Comment: And do you know some example with vertex shader on a JSON model that I could use as a guide?

Comment: ... the one of the second example you quoted maybe ?